# substring first position globalid value

Tags: c#, substring

I have string and need return first globalid value - 8679926300927194610

My string:

```
 string erservice = "globalid=8679926300927194610,ou=services,globalid=00000000000000000000"
```

I used substring:

```
string result = erservice.Substring(9, 19);
```

How to solve using another method?

Comment: Do you think there is something wrong with your solution? Would the length of globalid number change ? Try: `string str = erservice.Split(',').First().Split('=').Last();`

Comment: @Habib, thank you. I prefer you answer

Answer (score 3):

How about using regex?

```
string erservice = "globalid=8679926300927194610,ou=services,globalid=00000000000000000000";
var globalid = Regex.Match(erservice, @"globalid=(\d+)").Groups[1].Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably grab it more like this. Basically, find the `globalid=` key, substring to its value, then remove anything that comes after its comma. Of course, your way is much cleaner if you aren't dealing with arguments that change position or length.

```
const string globalIdName = "globalid=";


string erservice = ...;

var startIndex = erservice.IndexOf(globalIdName);
if (startIndex> -1)
{
    var ret = erservice.SubString(startIndex + globalIdName.Length);

    var comma = ret.IndexOf(',');

    if(comma > -1)
    {
       ret = ret.Remove(comma);
    }

    return ret;
}
else
{
    throw new ArgumentException();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [Regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
string result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(
    erservice, 
    "^globalid=([0-9]+).*$", 
    "$1");
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what information you need to get.

Here are a couple techniques that may work for you.

```
string erservice = "globalid=8679926300927194610,ou=services,globalid=00000000000000000000";

int lastIndex = 0;
int index;
while ((index = erservice.IndexOf("globalid", lastIndex)) >= 0)
{
    // Contains everything including and after each globalid=
    string part = erservice.Substring(index);
    lastIndex = index + 1;

    // do work
}

foreach (string section in erservice.Split(','))
{
    // Gets each key/value pair
    string[] parts = section.Split('=');
    string key = parts[0];
    string value = parts[1];

    // do work
}
```